# What is the unit of this value

Tags: linux, cpu-frequency, sysfs

I was trying to get frequecy from my device at run time. I used this device node

```
sudo cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/cpuinfo_min_freq
```

It gave me 60000.
I tried this one

```
cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/cpuinfo_cur_freq
```

I get 396000.

What is the unit of these values. Is it 60000 Hz or Mhz?

Comment: Also, do note the CPU frequency is likely to change depending on system load.  A lower clock speed on the CPU equals power savings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values are given in kHz (see the [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/user-guide.txt)). So 60000 is 60 MHz, 396000 is 396 MHz.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. I will look into the documentation from now on.